# How to adjust the size of y axis labels only in R?

Tags: r, plot, label

How can I adjust only the size of Y-axis labels in R?

I know that cex.axis alters the size of the axis labels but it only affects the x-axis. Why, and how can I adjust the y axis?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

ucfagls is right, providing you use the `plot()` command. If not, please give us more detail.

In any case, you can control every axis seperately by using the `axis()` command and the `xaxt`/`yaxt` options in `plot()`. Using the data of ucfagls, this becomes :

```
plot(Y ~ X, data=foo,yaxt="n")
axis(2,cex.axis=2)
```

the option yaxt="n" is necessary to avoid that the plot command plots the y-axis without changing. For the x-axis, this works exactly the same :

```
plot(Y ~ X, data=foo,xaxt="n")
axis(1,cex.axis=2)
```

See also the help files ?par and ?axis

---

Edit : as it is for a barplot, look at the options cex.axis and cex.names :

```
tN <- table(sample(letters[1:5],100,replace=T,p=c(0.2,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.2)))

op <- par(mfrow=c(1,2))
barplot(tN, col=rainbow(5),cex.axis=0.5) # for the Y-axis
barplot(tN, col=rainbow(5),cex.names=0.5) # for the X-axis
par(op)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi there,sorry for beeing unprecise (again). Actually I am running a barplot with numerical X-axis but wiht strings for y axis labels. I guess that the cex.axis in barplot cannot handle text since in the help for par it says "cex.axis = expansion factor for numeric axis labels." I guess I have to use your approach with the extra axis command to modify my y-axis.  Many thanks

Comment: @Jens; If using `barplot()` separate `axis()` calls won't work because the bar labels are not an "axis". To use `axis()` you'd need to ave the bar mid points (these are returned by `barplot()`). Using a `text()` call with clipping turned off might also be a way to do a custom "axis" for a barplot.

Comment: @ucfagls On my system, that does work actually for the Y axis. For the X axis it gives a wrong result. I adapted my answer for the barplot.

Comment: @Jens Would you be as kind as to edit your question and specify this is for a barplot? thx

Comment: indeed, but whether the y-axis is an "axis" or a labelled set of bars depends on the `horiz` argument of the `barplot()`. Jens's problem was that `cex.axis` didn't work for one of the axes (in his case the x-axis so we presume he was using default `horiz = FALSE`). My comment was, not that `axis()` is wrong, just that the control over the x-axis (in Jens' case), or the bar labels, can not be managed with a separate call to `axis()` [well, easily]. Ultimately this boils down to not reading `?barplot` and not providing us here with a reproducible example showing the problem.

Answer (score 23):

As the title suggests that we want to adjust the size of the labels and not the tick marks I figured that I actually might add something to the question, you need to use the mtext() if you want to specify one of the label sizes, or you can just use `par(cex.lab=2)` as a simple alternative. Here's a more advanced mtext() example:

```
set.seed(123)
foo <- data.frame(X = rnorm(10), Y = rnorm(10))
plot(Y ~ X, data=foo,
     yaxt="n", ylab="", 
     xlab="Regular boring x", 
     pch=16,
     col="darkblue")
axis(2,cex.axis=1.2)
mtext("Awesome Y variable", side=2, line=2.2, cex=2)
```

[image]

You may need to adjust the `line=` option to get the optimal positioning of the text but apart from that it's really easy to use.

Answer (score 9):

Don't know what you are doing (helpful to show what you tried that didn't work), but your claim that `cex.axis` only affects the x-axis is not true:

```
set.seed(123)
foo <- data.frame(X = rnorm(10), Y = rnorm(10))
plot(Y ~ X, data = foo, cex.axis = 3)
```

at least for me with:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.11.1 Patched (2010-08-17 r52767)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=C              LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[8] base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_0.8.8 proto_0.3-8   reshape_0.8.3 plyr_1.2.1   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] digest_0.4.2 tools_2.11.1
```

Also, `cex.axis` affects the labelling of tick marks. `cex.lab` is used to control what R call the axis labels.

```
plot(Y ~ X, data = foo, cex.lab = 3)
```

but even that works for both the x- and y-axis.

---

Following up Jens' comment about using `barplot()`. Check out the `cex.names` argument to `barplot()`, which allows you to control the bar labels:

dat <- rpois(10, 3)
names(dat) <- LETTERS[1:10]
barplot(dat, cex.names = 3, cex.axis = 2)

As you mention that `cex.axis` was only affecting the x-axis I presume you had `horiz = TRUE` in your `barplot()` call as well? As the bar labels are not drawn with an `axis()` call, applying Joris' (otherwise very useful) answer with individual `axis()` calls won't help in this situation with you using `barplot()`

HTH