# Formatting Issue with barchart() of Cluster Analysis

Tags: r, data-visualization, cluster-analysis

I've created a segment profile plot of my cluster analysis but I'm having an issue with the formatting of a `barchart()` command. Here is the chart I created. The obvious issue is that my lines are too close together to read. [image: The obvious issue is that my lines are too close together]

Here you can see the code I used to create this chart. Can someone tell me what to add in order to make this chart readable? Below is an example of my code used.

R code for reproducing the clustering and PCA we used:

```
## if not installed, install: install.packages("flexclust")
library("flexclust")
load("vacpref.RData")
cl6 <- kcca(vacpref, k=vacpref6, control=list(iter=0),
            simple=FALSE, save.data=TRUE)
summary(cl6)
```

hierarchical clustering of the variables

```
varhier <- hclust(dist(t(vacpref)), "ward")
par(mar=c(0,0,0,15))
plot(as.dendrogram(varhier), xlab="", horiz=TRUE,yaxt="n")
```

principal component projection

```
vacpca <- prcomp(vacpref)
```

R code for generating the Segment Separation Plot

```
pairs(cl6, project=vacpca, which=1:3, asp=TRUE,points=FALSE, 
      hull.args=list(density=10))
```

R code for generating the Segment Positioning Plot:

```
col <- flxColors(1:6)
col[c(1,3)] <- flxColors(1:4, "light")[c(1,3)]
par(mar=rep(0,4))
plot(cl6, project=vacpca, which=2:3,
     col=col,asp=TRUE,points=F,hull.args=list(density=10),axes=FALSE)
projAxes(vacpca, minradius=.5, which=2:3, lwd=2, col=”darkblue”)
```

R code for generating the Segment Profile Plot:

```
barchart(cl6, shade=TRUE, which=rev(varhier$order),legend=TRUE)
```

The last command was the one I used to create my segment profile plot but I wasn't sure if the commands before may have affected it in any way. I'm new to R.

Comment: A dotplot or a parallel coordinates plot would certainly help to improve clarity and readability.

Answer (score 0):

One trick I often use is to change the width/height and resolution through exporting the image. Try this:

```
png("c:\\temp\\myCrazyPlot.png", res=250, height=8, width=12, unit="in")
  barchart(cl6, shade=TRUE, which=rev(varhier$order),legend=TRUE)
  # And whatever other plot commands for the same plot
dev.off()
```

Then go check your .png file. By tinkering the height and width, you can somehow adjust the spacing of the labels at the y-axis. You may even make its height longer than its width to let the labels spread out. (I think currently you can't do that because that's the maximal height of your screen?)

Comment: Thanks but it's not working. It skews the image like you said but maintains the overlapping labels. It does make it easier to read but not good enough for a report. Any other suggestions I could do in R?

Comment: @Brennen Sorry it didn't work. Please try the suggestion of [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778084/r-how-to-adjust-only-size-of-y-axis-labels).