# Is it possible to change the fontsize of barplot tick mark labels with pairs_barplot in R package vcd?

Tags: r, mosaic-plot

With a large number of variables, the sizing of tick mark labels is too large in barplots along the diagonal of a mosaic pairs plot created with `pairs_barplot()` in the R **vcd** package. Is there any way to make them smaller? Here is a minimal working example:

```r
library(vcd)
#> Loading required package: grid
library(vcdExtra)
#> Loading required package: gnm
pairs(table(ICU[,c(1,3:9)]), 
      diag_panel = pairs_barplot(
        gp_vartext = gpar(fontsize = 10, fontface = 2),
        gp_leveltext = gpar(fontsize = 8),
        abbreviate = 1,
        var_offset = 1.25))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-10-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Have you tried using the ```cex``` parameter? According to the ```VCD``` documentation that should scale text/symbols relative to the default. So ```cex=0.5``` should scale it down by 50%.

Comment: This is obviously a bug, `gp_vartext = gpar(fontsize = 10, fontface = 2, cex.names=.5, cex.axis=.5)` should do (see [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778084/how-to-adjust-the-size-of-y-axis-labels-only-in-r)) but doesn't, you should address the author.

Comment: I tried putting `cex.names=.5` `cex=.5` and `cex.axis=.5` in `gp_bars()` rather than `gp_vartext()` and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you cannot set `gpar()` for drawing the y-axis of the bar plot explicitly. There are two general workarounds, though: (1) Not messing with the font sizes but instead plotting on a bigger device. (2) Setting an outer viewport with a different `gpar(fontsize = ...)` that is used as the viewports further down in the plot.

#### (1) Bigger device

For illustration I use a `png()` device here because the PNG graphic is what I embed on StackOverflow. But, of course, you could use the same trick on other devices including those that you do not create yourself but via chunk options in R/Markdown etc.

I use a device size of 13 x 13 inches (as opposed to a more common setting of 6 x 6 or 7 x 7 inches). Then I can omit all of the `gpar()` settings because the device is large enough to accomodate the default parameters. I still set `abbreviate` and `var_offset`, though.

```
png("pairs1.png", height = 13, width = 13, units = "in", res = 100)

pairs(table(ICU[, c(1, 3:9)]),
  diag_panel = pairs_barplot(abbreviate = 1, var_offset = 1.25))

dev.off()
```

[image: pairs.table on bigger device]

#### (2) Outer viewport

Alternatively, I can create a new `grid` page myself and push a viewport with `gpar(fontsize = 7)` used as the default in this viewport and its children. Then I keep your `gpar()` settings in `pairs_barplot()` and just add `newpage = FALSE` in the `pairs()` call because I want to use the page I already created.

Then all font sizes are decreased so that plotting on a 7 x 7 inches device works fine.

```
png("pairs2.png", height = 7, width = 7, units = "in", res = 150)

grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(gp = gpar(fontsize = 7)))

pairs(table(ICU[, c(1, 3:9)]), 
  diag_panel = pairs_barplot(
    gp_vartext = gpar(fontsize = 10, fontface = 2),
    gp_leveltext = gpar(fontsize = 8),
    abbreviate = 1, var_offset = 1.25),
  newpage = FALSE)

dev.off()
```

[image: pairs.table with outer viewport]

Comment: Perfect. Both of these are great options. Thanks a lot.

Comment: David also just added a gp_axis argument to pairs_barplot and released a new vcd version on CRAN...

Comment: Oh wow, that was fast! Thank you.